# What is the minimum voltage requited to charge a cell phone?

Tags: batteries, telephone

When charging a cell phone, what is the minimum input voltage to the phone required not the battery directly, but the actual phone?  Is it actually five volts that the wall charger puts out, or can it be less like 4.4 volts?

Comment: This would of course depend on the phone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your phone has micro USB connector the voltage is 5V +-10% typical. Certain smartphones won't charge if this voltage is below 4.8V. 4.4V is unlikely to work.